# Rails 3 gem for writing help pages or wiki style documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, wiki

I want to write help pages which are not code documentation pages.

Documentation need not be too large, it will be 10-15 pages accessible from sidebar. They should be easily editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try Gollum from [here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/gollum). Or if you want to browse more here is a whole category at Ruby Toolbox for [Wiki's](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/wiki_apps)